# Vim keyboard shortcut: Deleting code without deleting the if statement

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

This is probably a basic vim questions to all those vim gurus out there.

If I want to delete a particular if statement and its closing bracket, but without deleting the code inside the expression, how can I achieve this through some keyboard shortcuts?

eg:

```
if (a == 2) {
    // do not delete this part.
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
      // code 
    }
}
```

The result will be:

```
// do not delete this part.
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  // code 
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your cursor anywhere on the line with the if statement. Here is the sequence of commands (will be explained after)

```
$%dd''.
```

**Explanation**:

`$` goes to the end of the line (cursor is now on `{`).

`%` goes to the matching curly brace (or parentheses etc...). Cursor is now on `}` of the if statement

`dd` deletes the line the cursor is on (`}` is now deleted)

`''` goes to the  line of the last jump. The last jump was when we used `%`. (cursor is back on if statement line)

`.` Repeats the last command (`dd`). This deletes the line (if statement line is now deleted)

**Result:**

```
    // do not delete this part.
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        // code 
    }
```

The indentation will be off so you can use `gg=G` (which correctly indents the file) to fix it.

If you do this alot you can make [map it to a key](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_%28Part_1%29) in your .vimrc or you can make it into a [macro](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Macros)

**Making it into a mapping:**

Example of a mapping in your .vimrc:

```
nnoremap <C-d> $%dd''.gg=G
```

Whenever you press `control-d` (you can choose any key, just replace `<C-d>`) Vim will run those commands, doing what I explained before followed by an entire file indentation this time. Make sure your cursor is on the if statement line when using this command otherwise there could be unintended results.

Comment: doesn't unindent the block.  which is just a few more strokes of course.

Comment: Read the line in the result section. Its true that I did not include the indentation in the original set of commands

Comment: to unindent *just* that section, prefix your command with `$<%`. Using `gg=G` will do formatting as I'm sure you know, and will do the entire file. this will possibly do things OP doesn't want.

Comment: Very true, I will fix that now (plus its less keystrokes :))

Comment: prefix, not postfix.  if it's at the end it will only work if for loop body is itself, a block, in this case it has a comment so it won't work

Comment: $%dd''. works great! Thanks guys! As a follow up, executing this command brings the cursor to the beginning of the file. If I want the cursor at the beginning of the for loop without typing such as "9G", would that be doable?

Comment: Well, you can just search for it using `/for<CR>` (`CR` stands for carriage return and means the enter/return key)

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively to Zachs solution, you could use this:

```
di{Vk]p
```

**Explanation:**

You start inside the `{ }` block, and with `di{` you `delete inside` the `{ }` block.

Then, you select the the if statement, which you want to remove, which now is two lines. `Vk` selects both, and you paste the block you just deleted over it with `p`. The `]` makes the pasted block be correctly indented (thanks, Kache)

There could be a more elegant solution to the pasting part, buth this was the first one that came to mind.

The anvantage over Zachs answer is that you don't have to move the cursor to the line with the `if`, you just need to be inside it (although you may run into trouble with nested `{}` blocks, which there usually are). In addition, you don't need to fix indentation.

Comment: If you add a `]` before the `p`, it'll paste at the same indentation level as the surrounding code.